# AS3: How to work with properties of the classes on stage (display list) from class not in the display list?

Tags: actionscript-3, properties, displayobject

[image]

Hi guys,
I have two objects on stage so I presume they are in the Display list as well (Progress_mc, Ship_mc). I have Calculator class which doesn't represent any visual shape or anything but as3 code so it isn't in the display list. 
What is the best way to work with the properties of Progress_mc?

**Example**: Calculator_as has to receive Progress_mc.width any time width has been changed and after some calculation Calculator has to send some calculated results to Ship_mc.x.

I was thinking if I have to addChild(Calculator) on stage so I can have access to those MCs in Calculator.as but this class isn't a visual object so I am not sure this is the right way. 
Or I have to do this (code below) in Calculator class and then try to access the properties but I this way wont work either because the properties wont be of the instances on stage:

```
private var prg:Progress_mc = new Progress_mc;

private var ship:Ship_mc = new Ship_mc;
```

Or I have to add them as children of Calculator and add Calculator on stage?
The other problem is that I can't just use setter and getter as static functions in Calculator because "width" property is a read-only and cannot be used in static function (error:?)

What is the best way to access those properties and manipulate them?

Thank you so much good people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming Calculator instance is sort of globally accessible. In that case, I think you have

```
public function setProgressMcWidth(width:Number):void {...}
```

in Calculator class. This function needs to be called whenever progressMc's width is updated. Later when calculator needs to pass some width to shipMc, it can dispatch an event such as

```
package {
    public class CalculatorEvent extends Event {
        private var _width:Number = width;
        public function CalculatorEvent(type:String, width:Number)
        {
            super(type);
            _width = width;
        }
        override public function clone():Event {
            var ret:CalculatorEvent = new CalculatorEvent(type, _width);
            return ret;
        }
        public function getWidth():Number {return _width;}
    }
}
```

and have dispatch code in Calculator like:

```
dispatch(new CalculatorEvent("shipWidthCalculated", calculatedShipWidth));
```

Ship mc, in turn, would listen to calculator's event like:

```
calculator.addEventListener("shipWidthCalculated", handleShipWidthCalculated);
private function handleShipWidthCalculated(event:CalculatorEvent):void {
    trace('calculator calculated my width to be: ' + event.getWidth);
}
```

Comment: Thank you catholicon. This will definitely work. What do you think is the best approach for similar problems in general? Do I have to use "composition" method always?

Comment: As far I think, composition should be used, if you can justify the composition semantics. e.g a button does semantically have a label, so it's nice to design it that way. Otherwise, if the semantics are just guiding that the types are relatively independent and just need a way to communicate, the a controller object(which can access everything) should setup the binding across those types.

Answer (score 0):

But if the calculator instance isn't in the display list, it won't receive any events.